# Create token for bank account information Stripe

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I am trying to create an ios app which safely collects a user's bank account information (with the intention of paying the user) using Stripe. Stripe recommends that I collect the bank information in an instance of `STPBankAccountParams`. This is not too bad:

```
var bankAccount = STPBankAccountParams()
bankAccount.routingNumber = routingNumber
bankAccount.accountNumber = accountNumber
...
```

Stripe then recommends that you tokenize the `bankAccount` for security purposes before sending to backend. They recommend you use this function:

```
func createToken(withBankAccount bankAccount: STPBankAccountParams, completion: STPTokenCompletionBlock? = nil)
```

The documentation on this function is a bit sparse: [Docs](https://stripe.github.io/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPAPIClient.html#/c:objc(cs)STPAPIClient(im)createTokenWithBankAccount:completion:)

I am not sure how to run this function in my code. I want to use this function and get the token, but I lack understanding on how to do that in code. I want to run something like:

```
token = createToken(withBankAccount: bankAccount)
```

But of course that and other things I have tried have not worked yet. Does anyone have experience running the `createTokenWithBankAccount()` function in Stripe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MadProgrammer's answer was very close, but did not actually work. I did talk with a representative from Stripe. For reference, he recommended the following code, which seems to work:

```
STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withBankAccount: bankAccount) { (token, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        else {
            print(token)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`STPTokenCompletionBlock` is closure (or callback), when the function completes (what ever task it was doing), it will call this block, passing you a `STPToken` or a `Error`.  You would use something like

```
createToken(withBankAccount: bankAccount) { (token, error) in
    // your code to check the token and error
}
```

This is a pretty common pattern and I suggest you take a look at something like [Swift Programming Language: Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)