# Allow user to input financial information for stripe express account?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

I'm trying to build a Patreon-like app: A creator creates an account where users can then subscribe for some price.

I have gotten to the point in my code where I now need the user to *add his bank info into stripe so he can receive funds*. I have come across questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65384081/how-to-initialize-a-stripe-connect-express-session-for-user-to-create-a-stripe-a), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54300951/create-token-for-bank-account-information-stripe), but neither shares any information on how a user can input his bank info on the client-side (they only deal with the backend).

*The connected accounts are Express accounts.*

**How do I make the user add banking information on the client-side?**

I have been recommended [this stripe page](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-link) but it does not show how to allow a creator to input banking info on client-side. I have also implemented the [example backend code from firebase](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/stripe/functions/index.js#L29) and updated it for my specific case.

**Update:**

I've also come across [this page](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts-bank-accounts) about *Managing bank accounts and debit cards* but it appears to be for custom accounts not express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe uses a hosted onboarding page for Express accounts. It's basically a form hosted on a Stripe domain that handles all the common onboarding requirements (e.g. verification documents and bank account details) needed.

Once the user has filled everything in they are redirected back to your site/app. In other words you don't really have to worry about collecting bank details client side, Stripe does it for you: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts

Comment: Im struggling to find where in that link that info is. I see the 
"Redirect your user to the account link URL" but no link to the docs or code... Edit: Perhaps this is related? https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide